# Однородные или неоднородные деепричастия

Tags: однородные-члены, деепричастия

*"Сделав водные процедуры и приведя себя в порядок, девушка удовлетворенно кивнула.*"

Деепричастия здесь однородны или нет? Я сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Основные положения

1. Деепричастия и деепричастные обороты являются в предложении **обособленными обстоятельствами** времени, образа действия, причины, условия, цели, уступки.
2. Обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастиями и деепричастными оборотами,   однородны, если **они относятся к одному глаголу и следуют друг за другом.**
3. **К одному глаголу** могут относиться деепричастия **одного вида**, поэтому они  всегда однородны. Деепричастные обороты неоднородны, если относятся **к разным глаголам**.
4. Обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастиями и деепричастными оборотами, связаны между собой бессоюзной или союзной связью.

Ответ на вопрос

**Сделав водные процедуры и приведя себя в порядок,** девушка удовлетворенно кивнула.

В приведенном предложении два деепричастных оборота связаны союзом И и относятся  к одному глаголу. **Они являются однородными обстоятельствами времени,** так как отвечают на вопрос ***когда***.